# Why is "What happened to Pandavas and Shri Krishna after Mahabharata?" the most viewed question?

Tags: discussion

Why is the question [*What happened to Pandavas and Shri Krishna after Mahabharata?*](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2158/2995) on the main site the most viewed question?

> asked: 2 years ago 
>   viewed: **120659 times**

---

<sub>If you are interested in most viewed questions on Hinduism.SE, run the following query:</sub>
<sub>https://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/579780/sort-by-views</sub>

Comment: Hmm... interesting question... One of the reason might be most of the TV serials finish their show after the Mahabharata war.. They didn't show what happened to Lord Krishna and Pandavas after war...so people come and search in google to know what happened to Lord Krishna and Pandava after Mahabharata... and they enter in Hinduism SE site... (just my speculation)...

Comment: It might have even hit HNQ list

Comment: @Tezz Suryaputra Karna, a show on Sony did show everything that happened after Mahabharata war including death of Pandavas and Sri Krishna.

Answer (score 2):

All other things being equal, the longer a question has been on the site the more views it will have gotten.  And this question was asked on the very first day of the site's existence, so without knowing anything else one would assume that it has a good chance of being one of the most-viewed questions on the site.  As a point of comparison, my question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3058/36), which was posted three months after the site was created, is my most-viewed question, even though it's about a topic that's arguably of relatively little popular interest.  So it's not surprising that a question which was posted on the first day of the site's existence and on a subject of more popular interest, namely the ending of the Mahabharata, would have quite a high view count.  But 120,000 is an unusually high viewcount, 20 times the view count of the question I referenced.  Maybe some popular figure shared it on social media.